# Maximum and minimum problem

Tags: calculus

If a factory can produce $ \ A(t)=\large \frac{36t}{1.5t^2+6} \ \ , 0 \leq t \leq 5$ pounds sugar **each year** , then **how many years after the production begins**, will the maximum amount of sugar be produced from the factory?

What is that amount?

**Answer:**

We have

$ \ A(t)=\large \frac{36t}{1.5t^2+6} \\ $

For maximum production,

$ A'(t)=0 \ \Rightarrow t=2 \ $

So after $ \ 2 \ $ years the production will be maximum.

The amount is $ 2 \times A(2)=8.2 \ $

Am I right?

I think I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: You can always [check it graphically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+36t%2F(1.5t%5E2%2B6)+from+t%3D0+to+5).

Comment: @A.Γ. I don't think the OP should check his results graphically without understanding the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @MrYouMath Then we think differently, because I think a visualization is the best way to understanding the process and verifying the solution. Particularly to understanding a mistake. I did not say "solve graphically".

Comment: To think about: what would be different in your solution if the question were *to minimize* the production?

Comment: @A.Γ. In most cases you are right but in this case, the OP might look a the graph and think that he was right by just considering the derivative. Then he might generalize this to other problems without checking the graph again. If the graph would be higher at the boundaries graphing would directly show the misconception but in this particular case the maximum is also the global maximum.

Comment: @A.Γ. The minimization example would be nice for checking graphically :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is correct, indeed since the domain is compact and $A(t)$ continuous the maximum exist and

$$A(t)=\large \frac{36t}{1.5t^2+6}\implies A'(t)=\frac{36(1.5t^2+6)+3t\cdot 36 t}{(1.5t^2+6)^2}=\frac{96-24t^2}{(1.5t^2+6)^2}=0\implies t=2\implies A(2)=6$$

while

- $A(0)=0$
- $A(5)<6$

Comment: what is the maximum amount ? is it  $ 2 \times A(2) =12 \ $ ?

Comment: The maximum amount produced per year is $A(2)=6$.

Comment: @yourmath I think here somewhere is your problem. Is the question to find the maximum production **per year**? Note that $2\times A(2)$ is the cumulative production under 2 years (incorrect if $A(1)\ne A(2)$), and it is not maximum. The cumulative maximum is after 5 years (since production is positive).

Answer (score 4):

To be more precise $A'(x)=0 \implies x = \pm 2$. Hence, $x=2$ is the only value in the valid domain.

For finite domain problems, you always have to check the values at the boundaries. Here you also have to check $A(x=0)$ and $A(x=5)$. Because these values could be higher than the extremum that you found.